# writing matrix in to text in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, file-io

I am trying to write a matrix into a text file using matlab. I used the code shown below

```
fName = 'Audio.txt';
fid = fopen('Audio.txt','w');
dlmwrite('Audio.txt', a, '\n');
```

but i am not getting all the values in single line.What I am expecting is one element in every line.How to make it happen

Comment: I don't think you need `fopen` for `dlmwrite`.

Comment: have you tried `dlmwrite(fName, a(:) );`?

Comment: Actually the last line of the code is enough. :)